# How do I change or update the email address used in Trello?

Tags: account-management, trello

Where do you go in Trello to update or change your email address?

The Account section only shows you this part in the avatar section:

> We're using eightballs@example.com. It may take time for changes made on gravatar.com to appear on our site.

And below that it allows you to set the email notifications.

Beyond that, there doesn't seem to be a link or a field that you can update your Trello account to a new email address.

Where does the magic happen?

Comment: Wishing this fix would be implemented, or ability to add multiple emails that are all my "gravatar" and pick the one for notification or merge two accounts. This is a painful workaround if you're entrenched on several boards for several orgs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an option in your Account settings, just go to `https://trello.com/username/account` or go to your profile to set your account settings.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

This is a request we've heard a few times already - at the moment, you can't. The workaround is to create a new account with the desired email address, then log in as the old account, and add the new account to any boards and organizations owned by the old account. Now grant co-ownership of the board to the new account (click on the gravatar on the board and there's a button) and give up co-ownership for the old account (again, there's a link to do that if you click on the avatar). Now you can remove the old account as a member.

Sorry, I know that's pretty complicated, but that's the only workaround we have for this right now, so if you really need to do this quickly, that's how.

Comment: Here's the link to the card on the Trello Development Board. https://trello.com/card/board/allow-users-to-change-the-email-address-associated-with-an-account/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/4e70fff862f86627d023acda

Answer (score 2):

This has now been implemented.

Go to your profile page - `https://trello.com/eightdays` and then click on the "change" link next to your e-mail address:

[image]

Then click on the "Send Confirmation Email" and once you confirm that is it you requesting the change the e-mail address will be updated.

Comment: You may have freehand circles but I have awesomeemailname@1337.com

Comment: Wrong site for free hand circles - so these aren't (free hand or circles)

Comment: Did you guess that username?

Comment: Ah yes, the cold tyranny of automated ovals.