# Change e-mail address tied to account

Tags: trello

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change or update the email address used in Trello?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18915/how-do-i-change-or-update-the-email-address-used-in-trello)

I don't see a way to change the e-mail address Trello has for my account. [Now that Notifications are working](http://blog.trello.com/on-email-notifications/).

I need to change the address associated with my account, is this not possible, or am I somehow looking right past where to change it?

Comment: @phwd Where is the duplicate question, I'd like to see the previous discussion. Before posting I searched for email with the Trello tag and only found 2 prior questions, neither of which was about changing the address.

Comment: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18915/how-do-i-change-or-update-the-email-address-used-in-trello It's at the top of this post.

Comment: @Sean You can now change your email address in Trello from your Profile page (click on your avatar in the upper-right corner of Trello and choose Profile).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to change your email address.

This has been [listed as a bug](https://trello.com/card/board/allow-users-to-change-the-email-address-associated-with-an-account/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/4e70fff862f86627d023acda) and is on their Trello Development Board, which [you can view here](https://trello.com/board/trello-development/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c).

Comment: Thanks, Barry. Seems like a crazy oversight. Good suggestions on the card re: multiple addresses as well.

Comment: @Barry You can now change your email address in Trello from your Profile page (click on your avatar in the upper-right corner of Trello and choose Profile).