# How to find out / change email address of my Trello account?

Tags: trello

My Trello password is remembered by the browser, but I do not remember what email I have specified when I registered the account. So I can't login anywhere else, neither can I use forgotten password functionality.

1. How can I see the email associated with the account?
2. How can I change the email associated with the account?

**EDIT**:
A helpful commenter pointed out that the second question is discussed [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18915/how-do-i-change-or-update-the-email-address-used-in-trello)

Comment: You should be able to see your email address on your account page, but that appears to have gotten messed up in a recent release.  We'll get it fixed ASAP

Comment: This is two questions. Question 2 is answered here: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18915/how-do-i-change-or-update-the-email-address-used-in-trello

Comment: @phwd: First of all, I'd like to thank you for you helpful edits and comments. I also would like to acknowledge that I realize, that you are a diamond moderator, and most likely know what you are doing. Having said that, could please provide any reference, that backs up that two closely related questions can't be discussed in one post? A FAQ entry link or a link to discussion on meta would be what I'm after.

Comment: @zespri you are definitely right there is no section in the FAQ that states two related questions cannot be in the same post. But common place wise it's easier for users to establish a 1-1 question-answer for voting up useful questions/answers. I wish I could point you to a canonical resource that says this but at the moment I cannot. I'll talk to the rest of the mods about putting a meta post to discuss it with the community. Sorry about that. I'll leave the edit as it is. Good catch and carry on :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://trello.com/my redirects to your account profile.  You can see your email address there.

You can see other settings at https://trello.com/my/account.

Per the comments and your edit, the other question is discussed in another place.